# How can I pull a new branch from GitLab in Eclipse in an existing project

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, branch, egit

I just started to work with Eclipse and GitLab. In Eclipse I pulled my ABranch. Now I created an extra branch in GitLab, but I can't get the new branch in Eclipse.

- I created a project in Gitlab with 2 branches (Master and Abranch).
- In Eclipse I only pulled the Abranch and pushed the changes back.
- In Gitlab I merged the changes to Master and also added an extra branch (testtesttest).
- Now I try to recieve the other branches in Eclipse.

Can you help me without using commands?

In tried to fetch from upstream with right-click at my repository but I can only see my 'origin/Abranch' under Remote tracking. I can't get my Master and Testtesttest in.
Fetching says everything is up to date.
I've got a screenshot below.

[Screenshot (empty) fetch results, here I expected my Master and Testtesttest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rSJF.png)

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the repository, choose _Properties_ and tell what do you have configured for _remote > origin > fetch_ (is it `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all a bug in Eclipse was likely the issue.
I also had Eclipse freezing at some moments. It's fixed with the following update:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099477/

Answer (score 0):

Try `git fetch` in your project root location.

Comment: The question is about EGit. Git on the command line may not be installed at all.